# Is there a fast way to copy the same array to another thousands of times at different offsets?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, audio

I am trying to create a sound reverb effect. It works just fine but there is a problem: it is copying a huge array thousands of times at different offsets and with different volume and it takes 10 minutes to process a small reverb effect on a 4 minute audio sample. Is there a way to speed up the process? I can easily make a list of all the delays if needed.

Edit: Here is my code. Is there a better way to achieve the same or similar result? SoundSource is a class that contains a sound along with a position. WaveNode contains a position as well as an ArrayList of WavePath instances which define various parameters about the echoes. Please tell me if something else is unclear.

```
public static double[][] render(int sampleLength, int sampleRate, int depth) //depth is number of echoes, must be at least 0
{
    init(sampleLength, sampleRate);

    for (int iSource = 0; iSource < sourceList.size(); iSource++)
    {
        renderNode(sourceList.get(iSource).getSoundSource(), sourceList.get(iSource), 0, depth);
    }

    double[][] r = sampleData.clone();
    sampleData = null;
    return r;
}

private static void renderNode(SoundSource source, WaveNode node, int curDepth, int maxDepth)
{
    SoundSource newSource;
    WaveNode newNode;
    WavePath path;

    addSource(source.clone(), node.smoothing, node.decay);

    if (curDepth < maxDepth)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < node.getPathList().size(); i++)
        {
            path = node.getPathList().get(i);
            newNode = findReflection(path.destId);
            newSource = SoundSource.reflection(SoundSource.swapData(source, Filter.amplify(source.getSampleData(), path.decay)), newNode.getPos(), path.smoothing);
            renderNode(newSource, newNode, curDepth + 1, maxDepth);
        }
    }
}

private static void addSource(SoundSource source, double smoothing, double decay)
{
    Vector3d pos, pos2;
    double dist, volume, soundPos, sample;
    int delay;
    double[] sourceData;

    for (int channel = 0; channel < 2; channel++)
    {
        pos = source.getPos();
        pos2 = new Vector3d(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
        pos2.x += earDist / 2 - earDist * channel;

        dist = Math.max(pos2.length() + source.getSourceDist(), 0.000001);
        volume = decay / dist;
        delay = (int)(dist / 343.2 * sampleRate);

        sourceData = source.getSampleData();

        sample = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < Math.min(sourceData.length, sampleLength - delay); j++)
        {
            sample = sourceData[j] / smoothing + sample * (1 - 1 / smoothing);
            sampleData[channel][j + delay] += sample * volume;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's the same array just at different offsets, do you really need to copy every time? Would it be possible just to offset into the same array and reuse that?

Comment: Are you copying arrays, or the elements of one into another? Can you show us some code?

Comment: Please show us how you are actually doing this. We can't really tell you how to improve it without seeing what you are already doing.

Comment: Make it please more readable by dropping the COBOL-style variable declaration sections. Then replace division by multiplication, you may win a factor of 10.

Comment: Generally speaking, System.arraycopy the fastest way to bulk-copy elements from one array to another.

Comment: @maaartinus - In IEEE float division and multiplication are about equally fast.

Comment: This seems overly object-oriented for DSP. It is much faster to set everything up beforehand and then process it all in place as @hawk suggests. I also see what looks like a recursive method call in renderNode and this could potentially be wreaking havoc on the Java stack. I think the problem is that you just don't need to be copying all the arrays and shouldn't be using so many objects during the calculations.

Comment: Give an example of one of your array copy operations.  It's not possible to divine them from the above listing.

Comment: @HotLicks I see two calls to `clone`, one that appears to copy the output in `render` and one inside `renderNode` (which goes on to recursively call itself in a loop). I actually don't understand the need for either of them because it looks like in both cases the array that is cloned is only read from.

Comment: @Hot Licks: My [benchmark](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4971686/published/maaartin/so/MulDivBenchmark.java) doesn't [agree](https://microbenchmarks.appspot.com/runs/95007945-1f2d-427b-bf74-9d2d0b9787b2) with you!

Comment: Yeah, my code is kind of a mess. I'm not very experienced with coding in general. What I was referring to with 'copy' was the loop inside addSource() which adds each array element after modifying it.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks, using multiplication cut the time by about 10%. It's a little but doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Radiodef I deleted the one in renderNode which was indeed unnecessary but the one in render is needed to allow the garbage collector to free the array sampleData if needed(it's static).

Comment: Try coming up with a solution that removes that one too. I assume that clone only happens once but it still seems unnecessary. For example instead of having sampleData as a static field instantiate it inside render and pass the reference as a paramater to the other methods. It's just another thing you're doing more times than you have to.

Comment: @Radiodef That's not really the issue though. I think I need a better algorithm for this, I have seen many that can make really long reverbs in just a few seconds and mine takes 10 minutes to make a reverb that is just a fraction of a second long.

Comment: You also should move the large block of assignments currently inside the outer "channel" loop in addSource to outside the loop. It doesn't depend on the loop variable so you don't need to be "redoing" it on each iteration. Then I'm basically not sure what to tell you about efficiency increases. Thousands of delays might just take ten minutes to process because each output sample needs to be processed thousands of times. If you want your code to be lightning fast you need to design it so it does as little as possible during the calculation.

Comment: http://dsp.stackexchange.com might be able to give you links for what are faster reverb algorithms. I don't have any. Most reverbs that are very fast do it by being "cheap", they are simple and unrealistic. They probably don't have thousands of delays, just enough to sound convincingly like reverb. The realism has more to do with numbers chosen and additional filtering.

Comment: @user2899864: If the other algorithms are that faster, then it's clear. You're computing some convolution of the original signal with many repetitions, right? Then you need an [algorithm using some Fourier Transform or alike](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_reverb). No low level optimizations can help that much.